# How does AirPlay handle with multiple source devices?

Tags: airplay, streaming, input-source

I have a bluetooth speaker and switching between two sources (Mac and iPhone) is a painful two-step process where it's required to disconnect the first device before a new connection can be made.

Could an AirPlay speaker act as an playback device for multiple sources at once? Or is it atleast possible to switch between devices on the fly (i.e. without having to manually disconnect the first one)?

Thanks

Comment: Connecting to an Airplay speaker from a new device should automatically disconnect other devices from it.

Comment: I have a Bose Color Soundlink and it accepts 2 connected sources.  So there is technology available to solve your need, you just need a device built for your need.

Comment: Good, so Airplay is better than bluetooth, but not perfect. I was aware that Bose has the technology to accomplish this, but avoided choosing an otherwise unsuited Bose product just because of this.  As it turns out, they're offering a wireless adapter which is compatible with other brands as it has analog line out. I`ll give it a try.